# Как отследить перемещение по DBGrid с помощью скроллинга?

Tags: события, delphi

Добрый день! Подскажите, пожалуйста, в каком событии можно отследить перемещение по ячейкам `DBGrid` с помощью скроллинга?

(мне нужно после каждого такого перемещения изменять другой `DBGrid` в зависимости от ячейки, в которую перешел первый)

Comment: По сути дела, в выбранном вами ответе нет никакого ответа.

Comment: Не пори чушь, попробуй и сразу все поймешь.

Comment: > нужно после каждого такого перемещения изменять другой DBGrid 

Вообще такая штука в delphi  работает "из коробки". Называется "связь Master-Detail". Вы дочернему источнику данных указываете в качестве свойства `MasterSource` родительский `DataSource`, в качестве `MasterFields` - поля, ссылающиеся на родительскую запись (внешние ключи). И все, при прокрутке родительского источника данных, будет фильтроваться дочерний (а вместе с ним и dbgrid-ы и прочие подвешенные на источник поля).

Comment: Согласен можно связать, но вдруг ему нужно что-то нетривиальное сделать.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Правильней будет обрабатывать событие AfterScroll датасета. Оно вызывается всякий раз, когда положение курсора в наборе данных изменилось.

Comment: Без разницы, как вы будете обрабатывать скролл. Проблема в определении текущей ячейки BDGrid. А как вы могли заметить, DBGrid отличается от StringGrid тем, что DBGrid не хранит в себе данные, и у него нет таких свойств, как Col, Row или Cell.

Comment: Большое спасибо за совет, учту! 

Comment: Да ну е мое. Грид привязан к датасету(будь то таблица или запрос) через датасурс, при перемешении по записям в гриде, перемещается курсор в датасете. Я как понял он будет менять содержимое другого грида исходя из значений полей текущей записи. Ну в связи с чем и вопрос в чем проблема?

Comment: >  у него нет таких свойств, как Col, Row или Cell.

Нет, и не надо. Скроллинг дбгрида однозначно вызывает скроллинг нижележащего набора данных. Поэтому AfterScroll - самое место для таких вещей.